# Spring Integration AWS - S3-Inbound-Adapter - deleteSourceFiles and Backup files

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

We need to delete the files after reading it from the S3 bucket, I could not find a option. How do we delete the source file after reading the file from S3 bucket and how do I backup files after successfully reading it?

Is there way that S3-Inbound-Adapter outputs the payload to a outputchannel?

Appreciate your time and help!

Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karthik,

The S3-Inbound-Adapter works like all other file-based adapters for the remote file system. I mean FTP and SFTP. We `synchronize` the remote directory with the local one and pick up files from there on each `poll`. So, the remove operation should not be as a part of `send file to output-channel` process, just because the remote transfer and process are separated over the time.

I only see the option for you to delete/backup file in the end of your reading process, e.g. one more subscriber for the `publish-subscriber-channel`, or `<transaction-synchronization` on the `<poller>` of `<int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>`.

But with that you should supply somehow the `AmazonS3Object` properties to invoke the `AmazonS3.deleteObject(String bucketName, String key)` in the end...

I'm sure that we will be able to transfer those options through the `MessageHeaders`, so feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter!